# Non-analytic function with convergent Taylor series everywhere

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there a smooth function on an interval in $\mathbb R$, not analytic on any subinterval, whose Taylor series at every point has positive radius of convergence? The Fabius function might be an example, but this is questionable since the n'th derivative has maximum $2^{\sigma(n)}$, where $\sigma(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which is not quite good enough using a crude estimate for radius of convergence if there are points where many derivatives are close to the maximum.

Comment: How about taking an example (like $\exp(-1/x^2)$) with this property at one point only, then doing a series with translates by the rationals and coefficients going to zero fast enough?

Comment: I don't understand the whole situation: how can a function with a convergent Taylor series expansion at every point and with positive radius of convergence be non analytic?

Comment: @Ali  if the Taylor series doesn't converge to the function. In Gerald Edgar's example he didn't define his function at $x=0$ to be $0$.  The Taylor series at $0$ is then the $0$ series which is not equal to the function he gave.

Comment: This question would be a reasonable homework question in a course where you were broaching the concept of analyticity.

Comment: @Charlie: OK, I'll be giving a graduate course in complex analysis next semester. I'll assign it as homework and let you know the result :). Remind me if I forget. @Bruce: The set $A_{m,n}$ of points $x$ for which $|f^{(k)}(x)|\le mk!n^k$ for all $k$ is closed and contains no interval. Ergo...

Comment: wow           !                          

Comment: I posted a fairly extensive survey on this topic in May 2002 at http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387148 and http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387149

Comment: @fedja It's the kind of question I would ask.

Comment: OK, thanks, I guess I didn't do my homework on this one.

Comment: After I finally read some definitive history on this subject such as Dave's survey, what strikes me is how consistently many mathematicians (now myself included) have been ignorant of previous work in this area over a rather long time.  I don't offhand recall any topic, at least in analysis, where basic examples and results have been rediscovered, reproved, and republished so often, and I would guess that even today many mathematicians would not know about this work.

Comment: The Math Forum URLs I posted in my 22 November 2011 comment no longer work, but these from the internet archive still work: [Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009194815/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387148) and [Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009194829/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387149)

Answer (score 3):

We define $$\Psi(x)=
\sum_{k\ge 0} 2^{-k}\psi_{\sigma_k}(x-x_k),\quad 
\psi_{\sigma}(y)=\exp{-{\vert x\vert}^{-\frac{1}{s-1}}},
$$
where $(x_k)_{k\ge 0}$ is dense in $\mathbb R^d$ and $(\sigma_k)_{k\ge 0}$ is decreasing and valued in $[s_1,s_0]\subset(1,+\infty)$.

That function is good explicit substitute to Fabius function since it is smooth and nowhere analytic: even better, it is multidimensional and its analytic wave-front-set is all the cotangent space (minus the zero section). To prove this use Gevrey classes.

It seems likely that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is positive on a dense subset of $\mathbb R^d$. Anyhow it is a good candidate.

Bazin.

Comment: You can use the Baire category theorem to show that there are no non-analytic functions with a Taylor series with positive radius of convergence everywhere.

Comment: This is also stated in Dave L Renfro's first link above. See the part where it says "...Therefore, it is not possible to have an example in which every point is a (C)-point."

Comment: that's just stated for d=1 though